# Open() in Python not working using a variable involving datetime.datetime.now() in the filename

Tags: python, datetime

I have a program which tries to use open() to name a file using a variable which contains datetime information. the code i have is:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = ''.join(['log ', str(now), '.txt'])
log = open(filename, mode = 'a')
```

when I run this code, it gives this error:

```
line 58, in <module>
    log = open(filename, mode = 'a')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'log 2014-02-07 21:02:16.475880.txt'
```

this code works if I replace `open(filename)` with a string, even with the string outputted by the error. I have also tried formatting `filename` as a string using the str() function, but that returns the same error.

Comment: The colon character `:` is not allowed inside Windows filenames.

Answer (score 4):

The `:` character is invalid on windows filesystem.

Also, consider converting the date to string using the `strftime` function, and not by using the `str()` function:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked perfectly. except now it throws out this error:

Comment: @user3285560 the error message didn't come through on the comment. Try editing your question to include it.